# I am having trouble using FileReader to write a txt file to an array (Java), what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader

```
Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("rates.txt")));
            for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
                while(s.hasNext()){rates[i] = s.next();}
                System.out.println(rates[i]);
            }
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, it reads the last chunk of characters in my txt file, places them in rates[0], sticks null in 1-9.  I'm not sure why it's reading the end of my file first.  The contents of the txt are below..

```
USD 1.34

EUR 1.00

JPY 126.28

GBP 0.88

INR 60.20
```

It reads the 60.20, which is all it is recording in the array.  Any help would be appreciated.  I guess I could give you the results of running this code:

```
run:
60.20
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the data in the text file?

Comment: How is `rates` defined in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(s.hasNext()){rates[i] = s.next();}
```

In plain english, this says: While there are tokens left, put the next token into `rates[i]`.

So it will put the first token into `rates[i]`, then the next token into `rates[i]`, then the next token into `rates[i]`, ..., and finally the last token into `rates[i]`. Since `i` is not modified, all the values are written into the same element of the array, overwriting the previously read values.

Comment: +1 indeed, good find! @deliriumtremens don't forget to accept his answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

- Using `List` instead of array

  - More flexible, much easier to work with, takes advantage of Java Collections Framework, etc
- Not storing the currency symbol and the numeric exchange rate all in one mixed bag

  - ...but using a class to encapsulate the pair
- Using `Scanner.nextDouble()` to read the numeric exchange rate (which presumably you'll want to convert to `double` anyway)

So, something like this:

```
List<ExchangeRate> allRates = new ArrayList<ExchangeRate>();
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String symbol = sc.next();
    double rate = sc.nextDouble();
    allRates.add(new ExchangeRate(symbol, rate));
}
```

Note how:

- You no longer need to know how many elements to allocate in an array
- The symbol and the rate aren't all thrown into one mixed bag
- `List.add` means no counter that you need to keep track of and manage

  - i.e. the bug in your original question!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that line 5, which contains your while loop, reads the entire file input.  So you read your entire file on the first `for` loop iteration where i = 0;   The next time your `for` loop there is nothing left to read.

You probably want something like this instead:

```
List rates = new ArrayList();
while (s.hasNext()) {
      rates.add(s.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other potential problem: `FileReader` uses the platform default encoding. This can be appropriate to process user-supplied files, but if the files are part of the application, they can get corrupted when the application is run on a system with an incompatible default encoding (and no, using only ASCII characters does *not* protect you completely against this).

To avoid the problem, use new `InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), encoding)` instead - and realize that you actually have to pick an `encoding` for your file.